# Where is jcr:text property in AEM

Tags: adobe, aem

Which node has jcr:text property in AEM. Does it come by authoring a component or it is a default property that gets added to some node in AEM?

Comment: The default Text component uses "text", if you need to look for pages/components that may have a property named jcr:text you would need a query. See https://aemcomponents.dev/content/core-components-examples/library/core-content/text.html and the property.operation=exists for sample queries.